# Check if a string is contained within the string elements of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

We can replace:

```
if "ab" == "ab" or "ab" == "ac" or "ab" == "ad": # ...
```

With this:

```
if "ab" in ("ab", "ac", "ad"): # ...
```

All's well and good.

But now, if we change the equality (`==`) operator with the membership (`in`) operator, we get:

```
if "ab" in "aba" or "ab" in "ac" or "ab" in "ad": #...
```

Is there a better solution to achieve this, without using a for loop (and this many `or` operators)? I know I could do something like this:

```
if any(search_string in x for x in ("aba", "ac", "ad")): # ...
```

But is there **a simpler way** to accomplish this objective, **without using a for clause**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in type in Python that lets you search through a collection to test for substrings, no. What you have is arguably the simplest implementation of a substring search. **There is nothing wrong with using `any()` and a generator expression here**.

Don't get hung up by the fact that you are using the same `in` operator here. It is the *container* on the right-hand side of the `in` operator that implements the actual search, not `in` itself (apart from a fallback for legacy objects that don't have a `__contains__` or `__iter__` implementation). Python's `tuple`, `list`, `dict`, `set` and `frozenset` types all define a `__contains__` implementation that lets you search for something inside the collection that is equal to the left-hand side operand, which is what makes `if "ab" in ("ab", "ac", "ad"):` possible.

If you want to have the same 'clean' expression for finding matches for substring containment, implement your own:

```
from collections import Container

class SubstringContainer(Container):
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self._values = values

    def __contains__(self, needle):
        return any(needle in value for value in self.values)
```

and you could then use:

```
if "ab" in SubstringContainer("aba", "ac", "ad"):
```

You might even be able to optimise the `__contains__` implementation where you pre-compute some kind of index, who knows. Personally, I'd not bother, **unless** there was a significant performance boost from a more involved algorithm encapsulated by such a class.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility could be with functional programming approach with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
strings = ["asb", "ac", "ad"]

ref = 'ab' # reference

check = any(map(lambda s: ref in s, strings))

if check: 
    ...
```

Edit: without `lambda`: make a list containing a copy of the reference string and apply a pairwise comparison

```
any(map(str.__contains__, strings, [ref]*len(strings)))
```